# Align environment only slightly aligns left and right

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align

I have several separate align environments that all belong to a bigger optimization problem. The equations are aligned to the left and the iterators to the right which works fine with & operators in the align environment.
However, when using two or more align environments, I noticed that they do not really right align but only separate the left and right parts with a seemingly arbitrary horizontal space between them.

I am aware of how the align environment uses alternating left and right aligned columns, I just don't understand why the alignment is not to the far right/left of the line. An MWE is below:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{geometry}
    \geometry{
      left=3cm,
      right=3cm,
      top=2cm,
      bottom=4cm
    }
    
    \begin{document}
    
    \section{Introduction}
    
    Some introduction that is meant to show where the left and right margins of the document are. All equations are part of a bigger optimization problem.
    
    \begin{align}
        & \eta_{m, ht}^b \cdot x_{m}^b(t) + MaxP_m^b \cdot y_m^b(t) \leq MaxP_m^b & \forall m \in M_{CO}^b, t \in T, b \in B \\
        & -\eta_{m, ht}^b \cdot x_{m}^b(t) - MinP_m^b \cdot y_m^b(t) \leq - MinP_m^b & \forall m \in M_{CO}^b, t \in T, b \in B
    \end{align}
    
    Some text in the middle that describes the equations below.
    
    \begin{align}
        & x_{fm, m}^b(t) \leq M_m^b & \forall m \in M_{BA}^b \cup M_{TS}^b, b \in B \\
        & x_{to, m}^b(t) \leq M_m^b & \forall m \in M_{CO}^b
    \end{align}
    
    \end{document}
```

How do I force the align environment to **really** align right and left and not just slightly right and left? Neither the equations nor the indices are at the furthest end where they could be.

[image: One can see the different right alignment of the two align environments]

Comment: If I understand the question you want to use `flalign` instead of `align`.

Comment: note that align is mostly designed for setting equations and here you have two columns of equations so `a&=b   &  c&=d`  but you are leaving the a and d columns empty, so it almost gives the appearance of left aligned equations in the b column, with no alignment on the <= operator and right alignment from the c column towards the middle of the second column of equations, which have no right hand side (d column)

Comment: Yes, `flalign` did the trick! Thanks a lot @campa !

Comment: Alrnatively, one might include all four lines in the same `align`, using `intertext` for the intervening text.